# Android prevent nested recyclerview from automatically repositioning

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview

I have a ViewPager as an item in a Linear Layout, with each item in the view pager containing a RecyclerView. The problem is, whenever the page initially loads, or when I change pages on the ViewPager, the view automatically scrolls so the beginning of the recycler view is the top of the screen, rather than staying how it is.

A .gif of the issue is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JqCiA.jpg). Note I am not scrolling down, that is the automatic repositioning.

How can I prevent the view from automatically repositioning to the start of the recycler view?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

you can add this attribute to your linear layout. The Linear Layout direct child of your scrollView.

```
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

Comment: It disables childview's focus.So it is not touchable or clickable anymore... Any suggestion or alternative for this issue?

Comment: @Harshit Thanks, It solve my issue

Comment: Why does that help?

Answer (score 7):

We have a similar problem. We have a vertical `RecyclerView`. Each item of this vertical `RecyclerView` contains an horizontal `RecyclerView`, like in the Android TV app.

When we upgraded the support libs from 23.4.0 to 24.0.0 the automatic scroll suddenly appeared. In particular, when we open an `Activity` and we then go back, the vertical `RecyclerView` scrolls up so that the current horizontal `RecyclerView` row does not get cut and the row is displayed completely.

Adding `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` fixes the issue.

However, I've found [another solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37312042/4034572), which also works. In our case the vertical `RecyclerView` is contained inside a `FrameLayout`. If I add `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"` to this `FrameLayout`, the problem goes away.

There's even a [third solution mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38949303/4034572), which basically consists on calling `setFocusable(false)` on the child/inner `RecyclerView`s. I haven't tryied this.

By the way, there is an [open issue on the AOSP](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=222911).

Answer (score 1):

I guess that the problem is not on your recyclerview but on your viewpager. ViewPager has **setOffscreenPageLimit** method that used to define offscreen page of your fragment attached to viewpager. if you have 3 fragment attached on viewpager, you can set its parameter like this

```
viePager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
```

Whenever you change the pager page, its fragment would still on last state.

Comment: Thank you, this fixes switching between tabs resetting the scrolled position!