# Nested Recyclerview scrolls by itself

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a parent recyclerview that has 3 child view in it. The last two of the child are recyclerview.

```
Parent recyclerview
 - child view 1
 - child view 2 (horizontal rv)
 - child view 3 (horizontal rv)
```

The issue is every time this fragment is visible, it scrolls itself to align with `child view 2`'s bottom.

I have set the parent rv to listen for scroll. This is what I end up with:

```
dy: 108
dy: 72
dy: 75
dy: 62
dy: 48
dy: 42
dy: 34
dy: 27
dy: 22
dy: 16
dy: 12
dy: 10
dy: 7
dy: 5
dy: 3
dy: 3
dy: 1
dy: 1
dy: 1
```

It seems like the starting `dy` of parent recyclerview is set to `0` to the `child view 2` rv. Everything above it is in -ve value. However, I'm not sure if this was the case as I'm still finding out what causes it.

Any fix?

Answer (score 176, accepted):

We have a similar problem. We have a vertical `RecyclerView`. Each item of this vertical `RecyclerView` contains an horizontal `RecyclerView`, like in the Android TV app.

When we upgraded the support libs from 23.4.0 to 24.0.0 the automatic scroll suddenly appeared. In particular, when we open an `Activity` and we then go back, the vertical `RecyclerView` scrolls up so that the current horizontal `RecyclerView` row does not get cut and the row is displayed completely.

There is an easy fix. Add this to your **outer/parent** `RecyclerView`:

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

I've found the solution in this questions:

- [nested scrollview + recyclerview, strange autoscroll behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37968010/4034572)
- [Android prevent nested recyclerview from automatically repositioning](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37782485/4034572)

Additionally, I've found [another solution](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=222911), which also works. In our case the vertical `RecyclerView` is contained inside a `FrameLayout`. If I add `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"` to this `FrameLayout`, the problem goes away.

By the way, there is also an [open issue on the AOSP](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=222911).

Comment: To be clear, you should add this to the parent of the `RecyclerView` which scrolls automatically.

Comment: curiously enough it happened for me only in release versions, debug version was fine

Comment: For me adding ```android:focusableInTouchMode="true"``` to the ```NestedScrollView``` that is the parent of the ```RecyclerView``` fixed the problem. Are there any side effects after adding this code?

Comment: it is not working if you have EditText in your recyclerView. it will make your EditText just blinking when do onClick

Answer (score 3):

Ah, I've been struggling for a fix. The solution is very simple actually. As a reference for me (and anyone else facing the same issue in the future), I just have to `setFocusable()` in the child view's rv to `false`, and it doesn't focus to that view anymore when the fragment is visible.

In my case, I have to set it programmatically after data has been loaded from an API.

Comment: This has solved it. Thanks. You just need to make sure that if the root recyclerview instances are the ones that should be flagged with focusable as false.

Answer (score 3):

Try this `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"`. It solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 2):

After a long search i got my eyes on parameter `reverseLayout` that was set to true. I replaced

```
horizontalRV.setLayoutManager(
    new LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, true));
```

with

```
horizontalRV.setLayoutManager(
    new LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
```

Answer (score 0):

Short hint to @albertvilacalvo answer:
If you use RecyclerView programmatically, you may handle setFocusableInTouchMode that way (include in your RecyclerView class)

```
@Override
protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
   ((View) getParent()).setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
   super.onAttachedToWindow();
}
```

The descendantFocusability solution fails if you need EditText in your child views, they would not get cursor anymore. I'm using ListView, custom (multi)touch and EditText in my RecyclerView childs. No sideeffects using setFocusableInTouchMode so far.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize layout manager in oncreate only or only 1 time dont re initialize it
recyclerview.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));

Answer (score 0):

Try to get rid of `ConstraintLayout` if you have nested `RecyclerView`s.
I've just replaced `ConstraintLayout` with good old `LinearLayout` and unwanted scroll disappeared!

Hope this might help someone :)

Answer (score 0):

i cant belive i fixed this by wrapping the nestedScrollView in linearlayout and giving the linearlayout the behavior:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

// your nestedscrollview or constraintlayout can be in here

</androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
```