# RecyclerView scrolls to bottom when data is loaded

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have some weird issue with `RecyclerView` since I changed my app to load the data from `Room` database.

I have a screen (a `Fragment`) which displays a Profile for a user. Basically it's a `GridLayout` with the first item (row) displaying some info about the user and then for each row I'm displaying three images.

The code for the `RecyclerView` is :

```
private void initializeRecyclerView() {
    if (listAdapter == null) {
        listAdapter = new PhotosListAdapter(getActivity(), userProfileAccountId, false);
    }

    rvPhotosList.setNestedScrollingEnabled(true);
    rvPhotosList.getItemAnimator().setChangeDuration(0);

    GridLayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), ProfileFragment.GRID_COLUMNS,
            LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);

    layoutManager.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
        @Override
        public int getSpanSize(int position) {
            // 3 spans for Header, 1 for photos
            return listAdapter.isHeader(position) ? 3 : 1;
        }
    });

    rvPhotosList.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    int spacingInPixels = 1dp;
    rvPhotosList.addItemDecoration(new PaddingItemDecoration(GRID_COLUMNS, spacingInPixels, true));

    rvPhotosList.setAdapter(listAdapter);
}
```

and this is how I load data :

```
    compositeDisposable.add(
        repository.getAccount(accountId)
            .doOnNext(account -> {
                if (account != null && view != null) {
                    view.showCover(account.getCover());
                    view.showAccount(account);
                }
            })
            .flatMap(s -> repository.getUserPosts(accountId))
            .subscribe(posts -> {
                if (view != null) {
                    view.showPosts(posts);
                }
            }, throwable -> {}));
```

Both calls return a `Flowable`, either a `Flowable<Account>`  or a `Flowable<Post>` where `Account` and `Post` are Room's Entity classes.
The two methods `showAccount()` and `showPosts()` pass the previously mentioned entity classes to the adapter.

The problem is this : the moment the data are loaded it scrolls to the bottom of the screen (which is also the bottom of the `RecyclerView`).

I'm not sure why this happens. Is it because of `Room`'s Flowable type?Cause previously when I was fetching the data from network and passing them to the adapter I didn't have this problem.

Edit : I'm using version `25.3.1` for RecyclerView

Edit 2 : This is how I'm updating my adapter class with `Account` and `Post` data :

```
public void addPhotos(List<Post> posts) {
    dataset.addAll(posts);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void addProfileItem(Account account) {
    this.account = account;
    notifyItemInserted(0);
}
```

Comment: It's already been answered by stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38949034/nested-recyclerview-scrolls-by-itself

Answer (score 36):

Did you try this? Setting `descendantFocusability` property of parent `RecyclerView` to **blocksDescendants**.

What this will do is, it will no more focus on your dynamically loaded child views inside recycler view, as a result, the automatic scroll will not take place.

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

**Note:** The property `descendantFocusability` can be used with other views as well like FrameLayout, RelativeLayout, etc. So if you set this property to your parent/root layout, it will no more scroll to bottom.

Comment: This would stop touch in recyclerView items.

Comment: @Abubakar no it does not. It just blocks descendants getting focus first in the beginning of loading items to RV.

Comment: if you have edittext in the "heaerRow" than it block it.

Comment: This worked for me. I had a recycler view inside another recycler view's row. This prevented it from automatically scrolling to that row.

Answer (score 1):

If you have some initial items, that should be at the bottom after new items loaded, then you need to give them new ids, if you don't want to recycler scrolls to the bottom.
It happens because the recycler remember that this items was visible to the user before update and after update he restore his state so that initial items at the bottom will be displayed

Answer (score 0):

In my case this line was culprit,

```
GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, SPAN_COUNT, GridLayoutManager.VERTICAL, true);
```

Specifically , last parameter which is setting `reverseLayout` attribute to true. Make it `false` and RecyclerView doesn't scroll to bottom of screen.

Comment: As you could see from the question, the value was already false. Nevertheless, that's not a solution in the case you DO need the reverseLayout attribute set to true.

Answer (score 0):

Although this questions is a bit old, seems like no answer is correct. I think what you need here is to listen to the Adapter changes and then scroll to the bottom on every detected change.

This is a working example of it

```kotlin
listAdapter?.registerAdapterDataObserver(object : AdapterDataObserver() {
    override fun onChanged() {
        rvPhotosList?.smoothScrollToPosition(listAdapter?.itemCount ?: 0)
    }
})
```