# nested scrollview + recyclerview, strange autoscroll behaviour

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-nestedscrollview

In a view pager I have several fragments, one of them uses a nested scrollview with a header and a recyclerview :

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/scrollview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.m360.android.fragment.Members.MemberDetailsFragment">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="20dp">

        <header/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:paddingTop="0dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

The tag "header" represents a complex layout that I didn't want to post here as it stretches out the code a lot.

when I switch between the tabs, it scrolls strait to the recycler view. The header is hidden, I have to scroll up to see it.

Any ideas on what causes that ? I don't wanna use a type in my adapter if I can avoid it.

Answer (score 32):

We have a similar problem. We have a vertical `RecyclerView`. Each item of this vertical `RecyclerView` contains an horizontal `RecyclerView`, like in the Android TV app.

When we upgraded the support libs from 23.4.0 to 24.0.0 the automatic scroll suddenly appeared. In particular, when we open an `Activity` and we then go back, the vertical `RecyclerView` scrolls up so that the current horizontal `RecyclerView` row does not get cut and the row is displayed completely.

Adding `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` fixes the issue.

However, I've found [another solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37312042/4034572), which also works. In our case the vertical `RecyclerView` is contained inside a `FrameLayout`. If I add `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"` to this `FrameLayout`, the problem goes away.

There's even a [third solution mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38949303/4034572), which basically consists on calling `setFocusable(false)` on the child/inner `RecyclerView`s. I haven't tryied this.

By the way, there is an [open issue on the AOSP](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=222911).

Comment: Did you opt for the second solution ? why do you think it's better ? thanks

Comment: @RenaudFavier I opded for the `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` option. I think that the 3 solutions presented do something similar (basically prevent the child/inner `RecyclerView` to gain focus, which prevents the autoscroll). However, [take a look at this](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=81854#c11) to better understand the issue.

Comment: @RenaudFavier I can use the `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"` trick to steal focus because I have my outer `RecyclerView` wrapped inside a `FrameLayout`. I'm not sure that you can do this if the outer `RecyclerView` is the root of your layout.

Comment: Ok I see. Thank you for sharing !

Comment: Ok, thats resolved my problem. But WHY this did the trick its the part the I don't get it. If someone could explain it. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

set`android:focusableInTouchMode="true"` for child Layout( may be `LinearLayout` ) of `NestedScrollView`