# Nested recyclerview: stuck while scrolling between groups

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, smooth-scrolling

I'm using nested RecycleViews to reproduce the way Google's inbox looks. Now, my problem is that whenever I try to scroll through the items, it seems to get "stuck" after a while:

[image]

The data is already loaded and it's rather "static" (it comes from a local db and it's loaded in a property of the main activity - the images are the only things which are retrieved dynamically and I'm using Picasso for that).

I'm already sharing view pools between nested recycler views...I've also tried removing the images, but I still don't have smooth scrolling...

Here's my main layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:background="#FFE7E8ED">
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
            app:titleTextColor="@color/colorWhite" />
        <!-- forcing focus due neste layout -->
        <!-- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36923948/recycleview-steals-focus-when-inside-a-nestedscrollview?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa -->
        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:paddingTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize">
            <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
                android:id="@+id/swiper"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/lista"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:scrollbarSize="4dp"
                    android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@color/lightgray"
                    android:scrollbars="vertical">
                </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
            </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
    <!-- Container for contents of drawer - use NavigationView to make configuration easier -->
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_viewer" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

And here's the layout of the recyclerview's item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/catalog_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textAlignment="inherit"
        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.WindowTitle"
        android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:cardElevation="4dp">
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/lista_noticias"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:clipToPadding="false"></android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

And finally, the layout of the internal recyclerview's item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="140dp"
    android:maxHeight="140dp"
    android:minHeight="140dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="0dp"
    card_view:contentPadding="2dp">
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/logo"
            android:layout_width="73dp"
            android:layout_height="73dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="false"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            card_view:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            card_view:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            card_view:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:lines="1"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Title"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            card_view:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            card_view:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/logo"
            card_view:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/description"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/title"
            android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:gravity="top|center_vertical"
            android:lines="3"
            android:text="Name"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.SearchResult.Subtitle"
            card_view:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            card_view:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            card_view:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/logo"
            card_view:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/title"
            card_view:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread_inside" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/publishDate"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:text="10/10/2018 13:50"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Small"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            card_view:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            card_view:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Can someone please tell me what I'm missing?

thanks.

Comment: Perhaps the discussion here might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36923948/recycleview-steals-focus-when-inside-a-nestedscrollview?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Tried addind the attribute, but not working...not sure why, but the external recyclerview's scroll will change its size according to the inner recyclerview that has the focus