# Ripple effect not working for nested recycler view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a recycler view, each item of which contains another recycler view. I want a ripple for the parent recycler view item when a user taps on it. The following code creates a ripple when I tap the text view (@id/friend_name) but not when I tap on the friend_expenses recycler view.

I want a ripple when a user touches anywhere on this item (@id/parent_recycler_view_item_layout). Please help.

Parent recycler view item:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/parent_recycler_view_item_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?selectableItemBackground"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/friend_name"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="pare"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/friend_expenses"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/friend_name"
        tools:itemCount="3"
        tools:listitem="@layout/group_friend_expense_item" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Child recycler view item (@layout/group_friend_expense_item):

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/friend_expense"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a ripple effect just add this to the target `View`:

```
android:foreground="?selectableItemBackground"    //better in foreground not background
```

And `android:clickable="true"` may need also (if you don't set any `Listener` on it).

Comment: @Arpit Shukla May this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36923948/recyclerview-steals-focus-when-inside-a-nestedscrollview

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by adding a view to parent_recycler_view_item_layout that covers the entire layout. I gave it an elevation of 1dp and added that selectableItemBackground to this view.