# RecyclerView's DiffUtil scrolls the list when all visible items are getting replaced

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-diffutils

I am using a `RecyclerView` with `ListAdapter` in which I display 2 types of items: content & placeholder.

In this example the initial list consists of 10 content items and 10 placeholder items, which I then replace with another 10 content items (= always 20 items in total).

Doing this with `ListAdapter.submitList(list)` works as expected and shows the correct change animations. Like in this GIF:

[image: The Diff working as exptected here]

However, when I'm scrolling to a part of the screen where **only** placeholders are shown then `.submitList(list)` causes an unwanted scroll, like seen in this GIF:

[image: The Diff triggers a scroll here]

My diffing logic: (Should be fine, generally all animations work as expected)

```
sealed class MyItem {
    data class Content(val text: String) : MyItem()
    data class Placeholder(val text: String) : MyItem()
}

class MyDiffCallback : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<MyItem>() {

    override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: MyItem, newItem: MyItem): Boolean =
        oldItem::class == newItem::class && when (oldItem) {
            is MyItem.Content -> oldItem.text == (newItem as MyItem.Content).text
            is MyItem.Placeholder -> oldItem.text == (newItem as MyItem.Placeholder).text
    }

    override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: MyItem, newItem: MyItem): Boolean =
        oldItem == newItem
}
```

What could be wrong? Is this actually working as expected and I'm just missing something?

- I checked some solutions from other Stackoverflow questions already - mostly about making the RecyclerView and the items not focusable e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36923948/recyclerview-steals-focus-when-inside-a-nestedscrollview) - they didn't fix my problem.
- I also tried to use a normal `RecyclerView.Adapter` and do the
  diffing of the new list manually via `DiffUtil.calculateDiff(...)` - this has the same issue (`ListAdapter` uses `DiffUtil` internally after all)
- I managed to do a workaround by doing `adapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(...)` on the exact items which changed - this worked and doesn't cause a scroll, but I'm not happy with this workaround and don't want to apply it in all my features

Comment: Did you find an answer?

Answer (score 0):

try this in areContentsTheSame()

```
return if(oldItem is MyItem.Placeholder && newItem is MyItem.Content) true 
else oldItem == newItem
```