# Recyclerview in nested scrollview gets unwanted focus

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, focus, scrollview

I am have a layout in which a scrollview holds several nested views and 2 recyclerviews.
The imageview at the bottom has a clicklistener which lets the user see another picture onClick.

Problem is that when I click on the imageview (@+id/imgRewards) the 1st time, the screen always jumps to the top of the above RecyclerView (android:id="@+id/monster_view").
I already tried to use "android:focusableInTouchMode="true" in the scrollviews parent Linearlayout but that does not solve the problem.

Can somebody help me please?

Here is my layout:

```
<LinearLayout 
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   android:id="@+id/mainLinDetails"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
   android:orientation="vertical">

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressTitle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:visibility="visible" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgTitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />

<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/detailsScroll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:scrollbars="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtBasicInfo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/newtxt"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="500dp"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            app:columnCount="4"
            app:rowCount="4">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_margin="2dp"
                    app:cardElevation="1dp"
                    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
                    app:layout_columnSpan="3"
                    app:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    app:layout_rowWeight="1"
                    android:background="@color/card_default">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtDObjectiveInfo"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:gravity="top|center_horizontal"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                        android:textSize="14sp" />
                </RelativeLayout>
        </androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtDWeaknessTitle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:text="Monster Weakness"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/newtxt"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
        
        <androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout
            android:id="@+id/gridWeakness"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            app:columnCount="6">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_margin="2dp"
                    app:cardElevation="1dp"
                    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
                    app:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    app:layout_rowWeight="1"
                    android:background="@color/card_default">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imgIDragon"
                        android:layout_width="30dp"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/dragon" />
                </RelativeLayout>
        </androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/monster_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scrollbars="vertical" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtRewardsTitle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/newtxt"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@color/card_default"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtRewardsInfo"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <ProgressBar
                    android:id="@+id/progressReward"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:visibility="visible" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imgRewards"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtRewardsDescr"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:background="@color/card_default"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtmainTitle"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:id="@+id/titles_view"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:scrollbars="vertical" />

                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: add this to parent LinearLayout of RecyclerView > android:isScrollContainer="false"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"

Comment: Hi Elias, unfortunately does not work.